# Symfony2 & PHPUnit - Access getContainer()

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, parameters, phpunit

I have a problem with my PHPUnit test on Symfony2. To connect to my application, I use a web service, so I created a UserProvider. In my function `loadUserByUsername` I use Symfony2 parameters saved in `app/config/parameters.yml`. As I'm not in a controller I need to use the global variable `$kernel` and get my args like this:

```
global $kernel;

$url = $kernel->getContainer()-getParameter('myparam');
```

When I use my application, it works, but when I write my test like this:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();
$form['_username'] = $username;
$form['_password'] = $pass;
```

and execute PHPUnit I get this error :

> Fatal error : Call to a member function getContainer()

How can I access Symfony2 parameters or use `getContainer` when I execute PHPUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Symfony documentation [How to Create a custom UserProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html), under 'Create a Service for the User Provider' it states:

> The real implementation of the user provider will probably have some
>   dependencies or configuration options or other services. Add these as
>   arguments in the service definition.

So, rather than using a global $kernel variable you should be passing the relevant parameters into your user provider service by defining them as arguments in the service definition. For example:

```
services:
    webservice_user_provider:
        class: Acme\WebserviceUserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider
        arguments: [%parameter_one%, %parameter_two%, ...]
```

As with any service, your user provider service class must then have a constructor which takes arguments corresponding to those in the service definition and stores them in private variables for use in the service's methods:

```
class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private parameterOne;
    ...

    public function __construct($parameterOne, ...)
    {
        $this->parameterOne = $parameterOne;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I've been writing Symfony apps for four years and I've never need to use the global $kernel variable. I daresay there may be valid circumstances but in general I'd say it's to be avoided.

Comment: thank redbirdo, it works ! i pass @service_container to my service and it's passed in PHPUnit

Comment: @Remi then you should have accepted my answer, not redbirdo's XD He doesn't mention the `@service_container` at all. By the way as I replied in a comment to my answer that is not a best practice anyway so you should probably refactor your service a little bit :)

Comment: @Remi - it's really better to pass specific parameters / services to your service because it makes the interface / dependencies explicit.

Comment: @FrancescoCasula He's a she ;0)

Comment: @FrancescoCasula I was well aware that the container can be passed into a service but I didn't mention it because I don't think it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should not access the kernel by using the `global` keyword. You can always inject it as a dependency (i.e. `@kernel`). Still if your goal is just to access the container then you should inject just the service container which is `@service_container`. The right and best way is to inject just the parameters like redbirdo suggested (i.e. `%parameter_one%`, `%parameter_two%`).

Regarding your test you should create and boot a propel kernel in order to be able to use it.

I suggest you create a `KernelTestCase` class to do that so that your test can extend it and access the container and everything like you do in your controllers.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase as TestCase;

/**
 * Class KernelTestCase
 * @package AppBundle\Tests
 * @author Francesco Casula <fra.casula@gmail.com>
 */
abstract class KernelTestCase extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->container = null;
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $options
     * @return \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    protected function getContainer(array $options = [])
    {
        if (!$this->container) {
            static::bootKernel($options);
            $this->container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
        }

        return $this->container;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $parameter
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getParameter($parameter)
    {
        return $this->getContainer()->getParameter($parameter);
    }
}
```

And then in your test class...

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\IntegrationTests;

use AppBundle\Tests\KernelTestCase as TestCase;

/**
 * Class ExampleTest
 * @package AppBundle\Tests\IntegrationTests
 * @author Francesco Casula <fra.casula@gmail.com>
 */
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testMyMethod()
    {
        $parameter = $this->getParameter('whatever');

        // ...

        $service = $this->getContainer()->get('service');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this relevant to the OP's issue. The test fragment contains a reference to $client and $crawler which means they must be using the Symfony WebTestCase. WebTestCase boots the kernel for you and you use $this->getClient()->getContainer() to get the container. The question did not ask how to get the container / parameters from the test program but why use of the global $kernel failed when running a test.

Comment: I answered saying how to get the kernel (not by global) giving three different ways of doing that. For the sake of completeness I added also a way to get a kernel in a test case. So the answer is relevant also if you provide additional information you know...

Comment: Thank for your help it works with the arg @service_container in the service declaration !

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Unfortunately that is not a best practice so you should probably refactor your service a little bit. Consider passing to your class just what it is needed :)